# Сериализация массива JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив. Как его привести к строке? Метод `JSON.stringify` возвращает пустоту.

```
var temp = [];
temp['block1'] = [1, 2, 3];
temp['block2'] = [4, 5, 6];
temp['block3'] = [7, 8, 9];
temp = JSON.stringify(temp);
console.log(temp);
```

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам надо объявить temp как объект - они используются в js в качестве ассоциативных массивов

```js
var temp = {};
temp['block1'] = [1, 2, 3];
temp['block2'] = [4, 5, 6];
temp['block3'] = [7, 8, 9];
temp = JSON.stringify(temp);
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: ну, может, и правильно